# DBeaver MySql Bastion Tunnel

Tags: ssh, database-connection, ssh-tunnel, tunnel, dbeaver

I am trying to connect to a mysql db via a bastion host called bastion-stg7 on DBeaver, on a new to me Linux/Ubuntu machine. I have the same settings on this as on my old mac that it worked on, my ssh key has been updated and new public key added to aws and bitbucket and i can pull company projects from the team bitbucket so i believe my aws config is set ok. When I "ssh bastion-stg7" tunnel in via command line, but... when trying to connect with DBeaver i am given the below error. I am a junior and would appreciate some kind words and assistance in making the db connection work!

```
Can't initialize tunnel
  Cannot establish tunnel
  Cannot establish tunnel
    java.net.UnknownHostException: bastion-stg7
    java.net.UnknownHostException: bastion-stg7
      bastion-stg7
      bastion-stg7
```

I think that this is as i have only completed the Host/Ip field on SSH tab of DBeaver, and that I may need to add id_rsa private key to the private key field to authenticate or password to authenticate, but I never did that in tableplus (my old db manager). I believe this is as tableplus uses a default of ?.ssh/config where there is a bunch of related info about the various env's incl this, but i cant decipher it - there is a User (mine), HostName and UserKnownHostFile values under this 'Host', how does this fit into DBeaver?

Comment: I have the exact same issue, I believe it to be cause by a mismatch of my keys, which were used for authentication in the ssh tunnel option, since the error says "Cannot establish tunnel", but I retried to setup anew the details yet this remains. Did you try using your private key?
EDIT: Your private key must be OPENSSH

Comment: Thank you for your time, i have tried every combination and cant seem to make it work, however it works on the php storm db manager, so i am just using that at the moment. Seems to be better than DBeaver anyways imo.